# how to unset array key and value?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [accountNo] => 208773

        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [accountNo] => 9415238

        )

)
Array
(
)
```

how can i unset the last array so that it must display only first 2 array.

please help

thanks

Comment: What code produced the above output? What variable(s) are you printing here?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE profilenam = '".trim($arrUsr[$indxUser])."'";    $result =execute_query($sql,false);    execute_query gives me result one-by-one

Comment: is there only one element in each array??

Comment: do u want this output? http://codepad.org/4tHSKE5i

Comment: @diEcho , i dont want the account field i just want to remove the last array

Comment: how's this http://codepad.org/eIWXd8z1

Answer (score 2):

If these 3 arrays are the content of one array, let's call it `$array`:

```
array_pop($array);
```

Will remove the last one, and optionally return it's value.

> array_pop — Pop the element off the end of array

http://php.net/manual/function.array-pop.php

---

This does the same thing as `unset()` here, but for curiosity's sake, here's another way:

```
// Move the pointer to the last element
end($array);

// Get the key of the element
$key = key($array);

// Unset the item
unset($array[$key]);
```

---

Just use `array_pop()` though, the other method was for entertainment purposes only, but you could use it if you want to change the last element's value.

Demo: http://codepad.org/UFjal89X

Some reference:

`key()`: http://php.net/manual/function.key.php

`end()`: http://php.net/manual/function.end.php

Answer (score 0):

try this ( if i understand your problem)

```
 $output =array();
 foreach($input as $k=>$v){
    if(!empty($v)){ 
        $output[$k]=$v;
    }
}
```

### [WORKING DEMO](http://codepad.org/eIWXd8z1)